# Query now extremely slow after server change

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

After changing servers, we are now experiencing extremely slow execution times for just one query. When we analyze the sessions during the runtime, we see hundreds (sometimes over 1000) open sessions all with the same session id and they are blocking themselves. Here is an extract:

```
+----------------------+------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------+--------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| waiting_task_address | session_id | exec_context_id | wait_duration_ms | wait_type |  resource_address  | blocking_task_address | blocking_session_id | blocking_exec_context_id |                        resource_description                        |
+----------------------+------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------+--------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 0x00000005A3B83468   |        161 |              19 |           121058 | CXPACKET  | 0x0000000EB9B9C830 | 0x00000010BF029C28    |                 161 |                        3 | exchangeEvent id=Pipe8a2d88200 WaitType=e_waitPipeNewRow nodeId=12 |
| 0x00000010BE003C28   |        161 |              10 |           121079 | CXPACKET  | 0x00000008A1A0E9C0 | 0x00000005734964E8    |                 161 |                       93 | exchangeEvent id=Pipe79fcc6200 WaitType=e_waitPipeNewRow nodeId=8  |
| 0x000000050BFA1088   |        161 |              42 |           121092 | CXPACKET  | 0x000000058C7C12D0 | 0x00000010B484A8C8    |                 161 |                       27 | exchangeEvent id=Pipe5647e2110 WaitType=e_waitPipeNewRow nodeId=15 |
| 0x0000000DFB199088   |        161 |              20 |           121094 | CXPACKET  | 0x0000000E77A4DCC0 | 0x00000005A3B82CA8    |                 161 |                       44 | exchangeEvent id=Pipe915578ed0 WaitType=e_waitPipeGetRow nodeId=15 |
| 0x0000000E501A64E8   |        161 |              66 |           121094 | CXPACKET  | 0x000000088DB9DCB0 | 0x0000000E44591C28    |                 161 |                       81 | exchangeEvent id=Pipe79fcc8d00 WaitType=e_waitPipeGetRow nodeId=5  |
| 0x0000000E501A64E8   |        161 |              66 |           121094 | CXPACKET  | 0x000000088DB9DCB0 | 0x00000003714868C8    |                 161 |                       82 | exchangeEvent id=Pipe79fcc8d00 WaitType=e_waitPipeGetRow nodeId=5  |
| 0x0000000E501A64E8   |        161 |              66 |           121094 | CXPACKET  | 0x000000088DB9DCB0 | 0x0000000DC854B848    |                 161 |                       83 | exchangeEvent id=Pipe79fcc8d00 WaitType=e_waitPipeGetRow nodeId=5  |
| 0x0000000E501A64E8   |        161 |              66 |           121094 | CXPACKET  | 0x000000088DB9DCB0 | 0x00000010B3A25848    |                 161 |                       84 | exchangeEvent id=Pipe79fcc8d00 WaitType=e_waitPipeGetRow nodeId=5  |
| 0x0000000E501A64E8   |        161 |              66 |           121094 | CXPACKET  | 0x000000088DB9DCB0 | 0x0000000F39DFA4E8    |                 161 |                       85 | exchangeEvent id=Pipe79fcc8d00 WaitType=e_waitPipeGetRow nodeId=5  |
+----------------------+------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------+--------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I am not sure what causes this. The problem didn't exist before moving the server. We had a short period of time during which the query executed fast on the current server and now have the problem of slow execution times again.

Comment: Can you share some code?  The database engine went through a major overhaul for SQL 2016.  I know we had to update several of our procedures because all of a sudden performance went into the tank when performing JOINs on certain views.

Comment: Could be an execution plan on the old machine was cached and moving to the new machine updated the execution plan and changed it as well.  You can try checking the plan cache

Comment: Are old and new server both SQL Server 2016? Do you have the same settings (MAXDOP, cost treshold for parallelism, trace flags)?

Comment: Trying updating stats on all concerned tables, that's been the problem for me in the past after a migration.  Also, dump all your Execution Plan Cache: `DBCC FLUSHPROCINDB (@intDBID);
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`  if that works I'll write up a better answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I will get all the information. Currently, no longer in the office.

Answer (score 0):

Have you compared execution plans? If you have upgraded SQL to a newer version have you updated statistics? If these are different servers with the same database is the data the same? Is the indexing the same? I used to run a replication topology and would delete unused indexes on subscribers.

The self blocking isn't really blocking. I think they introduced it in SQL 2005 and it's just slowness.